# SpringBoot map Java entity to Json column in database

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Need help in mapping entity attribute of Spring to json column in Postgres DB using JPA hibernate.
We have a column in db whose type is JSON but cant find its corresponding mapping in spring.

Tried with this-

```
 @Column(name = "tags", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
 @JsonProperty("tags")
 private Map<String,Object> tags = new HashMap<>();
```

But with this, we getting error while creating db table
Any suggestions regarding this?
Thanks.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no out of box support for this. But you can use **vladmihalcea** library.

**Gradle Dependency:**

```
implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.16.2'
```

**Your Entity:**

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
})
class YourPojo {
    
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(name = "tags", columnDefinition = "json")
    private Map<String,Object> tags = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: It works with this.Thanks!
But the Annotations are now deprecated for this hibernate version

Comment: Cool. If it works you can upvote that will help others.

Comment: not worked with jpa 6, TypeDefs removed